# How can I generate "migration" DDL from NHibernate mapping files?

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql, continuous-integration, ddl

I'm using NHibernate 2 and PostgreSQL in my project. SchemaExport class does a great job generating DDL scheme for database, but it's great until the first application.

Is there any way to generate "migration" DLL (batch of "ALTER TABLE"'s instead of DROP/CREATE pair) using NHibernate mapping files?

Comment: *Generate -- Please proofread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look into [SchemaUpdate](http://morten.lyhr.dk/2008/03/nhibernates-schemaupdate-feature.html).  Very similiar API as SchemaExport but it only creates migrations.

Answer (score 0):

While SchemaUpdate very much answers my needs, it still has several problems. For example it refuses to put a new restriction on existing database column even if it's not gonna conflict with existing data.

I'm going froward to extend SchemaUpdate a little bit or, if fail, switch to one of that hand driven migration tools (for example Rails one).